# Mistake in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm doing a project but I have a little problem with a Frame, I have a problem with a table.

Well, I have this:

[image: My frame]

The source that have for the previous picture is:

```
public class Geotools04 extends JFrame {
private JMapFrame mapFrame;
static StyleFactory styleFactory = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory(null);
static FilterFactory filterFactory = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(null);

Geotools04(File[] files) throws IOException, CQLException {


        FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(files[0]);
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

        Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("MAN_COD = '01'");
        SimpleFeatureCollection features = featureSource.getFeatures(filter);
        FeatureCollectionTableModel model = new FeatureCollectionTableModel(features);


        for(int i=0;i<model.getColumnCount();i++){
            System.out.println(model.getColumnName(i));
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();


        JTable table = new JTable();

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2)) ;

        JLabel a = new JLabel("Capas existentes:");

        JComboBox layer = new JComboBox();
        for(int i=0; i < files.length ; i++){
            layer.addItem(files[i].getName());    
        }

        JLabel c = new JLabel("Atributos de capa:");

        JComboBox d = new JComboBox();
        d.addItem ("MAN_COD");

        JCheckBox e = new JCheckBox("Where");
        JTextField f = new JTextField("= '01'");
        JCheckBox g = new JCheckBox("Where igual");

        JTextField h = new JTextField("01");
        h.setEditable(false);

        JCheckBox i = new JCheckBox("Todos los registros");
        JButton j = new JButton("Consultar");

        frame.add(a);
        frame.add(layer);
        frame.add(c);
        frame.add(d);
        frame.add(e);
        frame.add(f);
        frame.add(g);
        frame.add(h);
        frame.add(i);
        frame.add(j);

        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(5, 5));
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setModel(model);
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

But I need that my frame look like this:

[image: my goal]

So, can you help me, I put all in a GridLayout but I need that the last table
be bigger... But I don't know how to organize the element for put in the way that 
I want to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

1. Instead of adding components directly on `JFrame` create separate `JPanel` and add all components except `JScrollPane` (which contains `JTable`) and "Salir" button.
2. Set `BorderLayout` for your `JFrame`.
3. Set `GridLayout` for that `JPanel` add components and add that `JPanel` to `NORTH` of `JFrame`.

   ```
   frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   ```
4. Add `JScrollPane` to `CENTER` of your `JFrame`

   ```
   frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   ```
5. You can add your "Salir" button directly to `SOUTH` of frame or you can create one more `JPanel` add "Salir" button to that `JPanel` and finally add `JPanel` to `SOUTH` of frame:

   ```
   frame.add(salir, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   ```

   or

   ```
   JPanel salirPanel = new JPanel();
   salirPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,3,3));
   salirPanel.add(salirButton);
   frame.add(salirPanel);
   ```

P.S. Don't forget to call `frame.pack();` instead of `frame.setSize();` before calling `frame.setVisible();` method!

**EDIT**

Consider using some other layout for your upper components, like [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)
or [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/) instead of GridLayout.

Answer (score 1):

I would give the NetBeans IDE with its GUI editor a try. Use the default free design layout instead of the GridBagLayout.

For eclipse there should be a plugin too.